# FileReader File not Found

Tags: java, filereader

The file is not a ".filetype.filetype". It is in the same folder as the .settings and the other project files. Why is this not working? The full path isn't working either, but strangely, a `Scanner` is working.

```
import java.io.FileReader;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileReader testFileReader = new FileReader("hotels.json");
    }
}
```

Comment: is your file name hotels.json. or hotels.json or hotels.json.SOMETHING?

Comment: Are you using an IDE (Net Beans or Eclipse) ? Then where is that file located?

Comment: error message or stacktrace

Comment: The code you've given won't even compile, as the `FileReader` constructor can throw `FileNotFoundException`, which is checked - and which is apparently being thrown. We don't know what the file is actually called, either.

Comment: Make sure the hotels.json file is in the same folder as the main Class.

Comment: THe file name is hotels.json. I am using Eclipse. The file is in the project root folder. I am genuinely lost.

Comment: Putting it in the same folder as the main class didn't work either.

Comment: Throw FileNotFoundException in the main() and show us the error message

Comment: I threw an exception and got no error messages. Huh.

Comment: I added a simple read() function, and when I ran, I got the following error.


Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: \hotels.json (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at test.main(test.java:7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Instead of a FileReader use a Scanner and put hotels.json in a folder named json:

```
Scanner testScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/json/hotels.json")));
```

and then use:

```
while (in.hasNextLine())
{
    System.out.println(in.nextLine());
}
```

and it should print out the contents of hotel.json

Comment: It's in the project root folder, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Try putting it in a folder called json and writing `FileReader testFileReader = new FileReader("/json/hotels.json");`. Also try replacing forward slash with backward one. Not sure besides that :(

Comment: That works, but when I try a simple testFileReader.read() I get "123", which is not the contents of the file.

Comment: 123 is the ascii code for curly brackets. FileReader reads byte per byte and returns the ascii code (afaik). I told above^^ how to setup a Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the period at the end of your filename.

```
FileReader testFileReader = new FileReader("hotels.json");
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not working, even without that period.

Answer (score 0):

Put the file hotels.json in project root directory and try this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileReader testFileReader = new FileReader("hotels.json");
       BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(testFileReader);
       while(bf.readLine()!=null){
           System.out.println(bf.readLine());   
       }



    }
}
```

I think it works.

Comment: show me your code at paste.org

Comment: http://paste.org/65767

When I try the read function, I get a "123" in the console, which is not the file contents.